# Parse.com reset password link expiry

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I am using parse back-end for my mobile app and has a forgot password functionality which sends a reset password link to the user's registered email Address. Recently, I have been getting complaints that the link is not working. I want to find out whether its a genuine time out or a bug.

Does anyone know what is the default time out for **Parse.com** reset password links that is sent via email?